# Validating construcor parameters determined by another parameter

Tags: java, oop, parameters, constructor

I have the following `enum`

```
public enum StudentType {
    Domestic, International;
}
```

and a Student class with the following constructor:

```
//Left out additonal parameters and validation
public Student(StudentType type, List<String> documents){

  if(type == null){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must provide Student type");
  }
  this.type = type;
  this.documents = this.validateList(documents);
}
```

and a private method to validate the list:

```
private List<String> validateList(List<String> validate){
   if(this.type == StudentType.Domestic && validate.isEmpty()){
        return validate;
    }
    else 
      if(this.type == StudentType.Domestic && !validate.isEmpty()){
        return Collections.emptyList();
   }
   return new ArrayList<String>(validate);
}
```

My plan to make the Student class immutable.

**Explanation:**

Only students that are International require documentation(passports, etc). Domestic students don't require any documentation.

In my `constructor` I check to make sure the type isn't `null`, the client must provide either domestic or international.

In my private validateList `method` I check the student type, and if the `List` is empty or not. If it's domestic and empty, return the list, if it's domensitc and not empty, return an empty collection, otherwise return the `ArrayList<String>` of documents.

My question concerns if checking the type in the private method is code smell? My concern is that one parameter(list of documents), is determined/validated by the type of student. If checking the type in the private method is code smell, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with the code you posted, but not the ones you think it has.

First, we don't know where `documents` come from. I assume it's just a mistake in the code, and that it's in fact a second parameter.

Now, the code:

```
private List<String> validateList(List<String> validate){
   if(this.type == StudentType.Domestic && validate.isEmpty()){
        return validate;
    }
    else 
      if(this.type == StudentType.Domestic && !validate.isEmpty()){
        return Collections.emptyList();
   }
   return new ArrayList<String>(validate);
}
```

First, instead of rejecting the argument if it's invalid (as you're doing for a null student type), you just ignore the argument and use an empty list instead. That is not a good idea in general. If the caller passes a non empty list, it certainly don't expect for this list to be ignored silently. If the list should be empty, then reject non-empty lists by throwing an exception.

Second: the last line of code suggests that you want to make a defensive copy of the list passed as argument. But you don't do that in the first branch of your `if` block. And since the two branches consist in storing an empty collection anyway, it could thus be replaced by

```
private List<String> validateList(List<String> validate) {
    return this.type == StudentType.Domestic ? Collections.emptyList() : new ArrayList<>(validate);
}
```

Finally, (and back to my first point), since a caller should never pass a non-empty list if the student type if domestic, you could make that impossible by using two factory methods instead of a constructor:

```
private Student(StudentType type, List<String> documents) {
    this.type = type;
    this.documents = documents;
}

public static Student createDomestic() {
    return new Student(StudentType.DOMESTIC), Collections.emptyList());
}

public static Student createInternational(List<Document> documents) {
    return new Student(StudentType.INTERNATIONAL, new ArrayList<>(documents);
}
```

Comment: I corrected my code, the documents should have been a constructor parameter. If the the student is domestic, then there is no need for documents of any type, the List collection should be empty.

Comment: If I wanted to do this with the constructor only, no factory methods, how would I do it?

Comment: As I said, by throwing an exception if the list is expected to be empty, but is not. You could also provide an overloaded constructor with no documents. But why couldn't you use factory methods? That's an arbitrary constraint.

Comment: I can use factory methods, just wanted to know out of curiosity if it can be done without them.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the `validateList` method in the following manner:

```
private List<String> validateList(List<String> validate){
   if(this.type == StudentType.Domestic){
        return Collections.emptyList();
   }
   return new ArrayList<String>(validate);
}
```

**Explanation**

As long as you simply need to return no documents if the student type is domestic, i combined two conditions into one. It is not really important for us if the domestic student has his documents or not, we do not need to check this.

Comment: Your answer and the one above are really good. If I could up vote this I would(new account), as I had written my method like this before. To me though it seemed kind of odd that if the client passed an empty list in the first place, to ignore it and return a new empty list.

Comment: Thanks. The idea is to keep code as simple as possible. With return Collections.emptyList(); you state your intentions clear that no matter what, but when a student is domestic, he should have no documents. Yes, it is not so efficient as to keep the initial array in case it's empty. But I prefer readibilty and simplicity over subtle performance improvement. It's a common practice in Java world, I guess. Anyway, I'd prefer JB Nizet answer than mine as it's more exhaustive.